# developing a wordpress plugin, have a few PHP Woocommerce related coding questions

Tags: php, plugin-development

Background:
I hired a programmer to create a schema markup plugin for me, the job was done but a few things have left that need to be added.

We added a separate code where it adds fields such as "Brand" "MPN" and others to each product page.
the user can then add his input and it is being added to the product page.

The issue:
Product Schema code:
the connection where that input will be taken from that field and added into the schema markup was not made, I'm not sure what part of the code is the one needed to be posted to be able to tell how to get that data but here are all the relevant code:

```
//Brand field
woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
    array(  
        'id'          => '_schema_markup_brand', 
        'label'       => __( 'Brand', 'woocommerce' ), 
        'desc_tip'    => 'true',
        //'type'      => 'text',
        'value'       =>  get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_schema_markup_brand', true ),
        'description' => __( 'Enter the product Brand here.', 'woocommerce' )               
    )
);
echo '</div>';
echo '<div id="schema_markup_attr" class="options_group show_if_simple show_if_external">';

function schema_markup_save_custom_general_fields($post_id)
{   

    $woocommerce_brand  = $_POST['_schema_markup_brand'];

if(isset($woocommerce_brand))
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_schema_markup_brand', esc_attr($woocommerce_brand));

function schema_markup_custom_variable_fields( $loop, $variation_id, $variation ) {

        // Variation Brand field
        woocommerce_wp_text_input( 
            array( 
                'id'       => '_schema_markup_variable_brand['.$loop.']', 
                'label'       => __( '<br>Brand', 'woocommerce' ), 
                'placeholder' => 'Parent Brand',
                'desc_tip'    => 'true',
                'description' => __( 'Enter the product Brand here.', 'woocommerce' ),
                'value'       => get_post_meta($variation->ID, '_schema_markup_brand', true),
                'wrapper_class' => 'form-row-full',
            )
        );

function schema_markup_save_custom_variable_fields( $post_id ) {

// Brand Field
        $_brand = $_POST['_schema_markup_variable_brand'];
            $variation_id = (int) $variable_post_id[$i];
            if ( isset( $_brand[$i] ) ) {
                update_post_meta( $variation_id, '_schema_markup_brand', stripslashes( $_brand[$i]));               
            }


The Schema Markup Code looks (for now) like this, and being generated by 
    $data["brand"] = ['_schema_markup_variable_brand'];

echo '<script class="my-json-markup" type="application/ld+json">' . wp_json_encode( $data ) . '</script>';
```